# Syntax Error while Summation Operation in for loop of Python

Tags: python, for-loop, syntax-error

I am trying to define a function to convert a binary number to a decimal number and check if it is an absolute square or not. I am passing a list of binary numbers as the argument and the function is supposed to print "True" or "False" as the output in the same order as that of the list elements; depicting whether or not they are absolute squares.

While trying so I am getting a syntax error in the ninth line where I am trying to calculate the decimal equivalent of the binary digits by adding the individual values arising out of each binary digit owing to it's position. 
Logic of Execution: 1001 in Binary means [pow(2,3)*1 + pow(2,2)*0 + pow(2,1)*0 + pow(2,0)*1] in Decimal. It's equal to 9 which is an absolute square of 3. So the output should be "True"

```
import math

n = int(input("Enter the total no of elements to check: "))
num_list = []
for k in range (n):
    print("Enter the number at position "+str(k)+" : ")
    num = int(input())
    num_list.append(num)

#print(num_list) for debugging purpose

def Binary_SquareRoot_Checker(input_list):
    for i in input_list:
        q = str(i)
        no_of_digit = len(q) 
        #For each element of the list, we need to count the no of digits present
        addition_num = 0
        for p in range (no_of_digit):
                r = q[p]
                value = (2**(no_of_digit - (p+1)) * int(r) 
                addition_num = addition_num + value
        #print(addition_num) just to see the decimal number
        root = math.sqrt(sum_num)
        if int(root + 0.5) ** 2 == sum_num:
            #Checking for absolute square property
            print("True")
        else:
            print("False")

Binary_SquareRoot_Checker(num_list)
```

I am getting **Syntax Error** at `addition_num = addition_num + value`

Please tell me why this error is being reported?

Comment: missing closing `)` in the line above (the line above itself is _technically_ syntactically correct; the missing closing parens makes Python assume that it is continued on the next line, but then the `=` is invalid, thus a syntax error on the "wrong" line)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the 20th line, change:

```
value = (2**(no_of_digit - (p+1)) * int(r)
```

To:

```
value = (2**(no_of_digit - (p+1)) * int(r) )
```